# Highlighting or filling in empty white spaces of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, image, uiviewcontroller, colors, uiimageview

I have a UIViewController that initially is of a white background and allows the user to color in the UIImageView of a certain color by touch events. When all is done, I would like a way to highlight or show the uncolored areas (the remaining white areas) of the UIImageView. Is there a nice way to implement this. I have tried messing with CGBitMap methods but I have not been successful without any errors in code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you simply change the background color of your UIViewController?

Comment: I would like to retain the filled in areas by user touches.

Comment: so your UIImageView has a white background that a user is drawing on?  Or is it clear? I was just assuming that you canvas is transparent sitting on another view that is providing the color white.  How do you want to highlight the changes to the user?

Comment: On a side note you could display your UIImageView then over the top display another view that you actually draw on.  This way you have diffs between your canvas and the original image.

Comment: It has a white background that a user can draw on, yes. Thanks for your suggestions. I managed to create a workaround.